# Libreoffice calc appears in launcher as a white icon

Tags: libreoffice

When i try to open a .xls file sometimes appear a white icon on launcher instead of the green open office calc icon.

Besides, when this problem happens, it doesnt allow me to open more than one file at a time and of course, the arrows next to the icon doesn't appear as well,

What is happening? is there a way to solve this?

Comment: This question is a confirmed bug over at LaunchPad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/bamf/+bug/1026426).   StackExchange sites do not handle bugs and so this question will probably be closed because of that.  If you want to help then using your LaunchPad account, add yourself as someone who the bug affects.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. See more details [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1026426)